# infopath 2013 multiple selection listbox showing blank value

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I create new blank from and add on multi-select drop down bind the value form SharePoint List Lib when i open the from for filling it showing no of item blank value in my Multi Select . How to Remove the Blank item from Multi-select Drop Down.